# Calculating FIT for Magnetic Sensors

Tags: reliability, current-sensor

We have qualified one of our magnetic sensors (80 samples, 1000 hours - JEDEC) with zero failures and we are asked to provide a FIT. The product is not repairable so I would think an MTTF would be more appropriate in this case, but in either case, how would you calculate FIT, MTBF or MTTF in this case with 0 failures?

Answer (score 2):

There are many on-line calculators you can use to get the MTBF from your data. One example is: https://reliabilityanalyticstoolkit.appspot.com/field_mtbf_calculator. Using your data at this site yields the following results: at 60% confidence, MTBF = 87,309 hr and a failure rate of 11 per million hours (since FIT is for 1 billion hours, the FIT would be 11,000). For 90% confidence, the results are MTBF = 34,744 hr and a failure rate of 29 per million hours (FIT of 29,000). The formulas and rationale for them can also be found on thus site (they are too complex to include in this answer).

Comment: Appreciate the response, the calculations and the link. I will need to evaluate it but this is a very good start. Thank you.